# Rogue characters in url

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how to get rid of rogue **"#.UvTYzLQ-eF8"** characters at the end of a URL?

My site is built using asp.net. It adds this at the end of the URL and looks like

```
   www.domain.com/page.aspx?pageid=23#.UvTdibQ-eF8
```

I cant figure out why this is happening.

I have tried to recompile the whole site but no joy.

Comment: i guess it is session id \

Comment: Are you using JQUERY?  that looks like the construct that jquery uses for AJAX loading pages

Comment: @Feuerwehrmann, you are right. there was a AddThis code on the page that was doing this. have changed it and works fine. thanks

Comment: glad it worked out.  if you want to keep Jquery, add rel="external" to the links and it will not add the hash at the end